# jqgrid mvc json format?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

Script:

```
jQuery("#grid_table").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAll", "Widget")',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['id', 'name'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55, sortable: true, editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10} },
            { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 200, editable: true }
       ],
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "id",
            userdata: "userdata"
        },
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: jQuery('#gridpager'),
        sortname: 'name',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        caption: "Wines"
    }).navGrid('#gridpager');
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetAll()
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var o = new
            {
                id = i.ToString(),
                name = "name " + i.ToString()
            };
            list.Add(o);
        }

        var result = new
        {
            page = "1",
            total = "1",
            records = "10",
            rows = list.ToArray()
        };

        string Jlist = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

        return Json(Jlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Json output:

[image]

And message: No records found!

What is the wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
string Jlist = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

I removed serilization line and then it works. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think as mentioned in your json reader "userdata" is not there in your json .

So please pass some null value or any value in your userdata field.